# How do I add multiple values to a structure from a sheet?

Tags: haskell

I wrote Tree RB in haskell, it looks like this:
`data Tree a = Leaf | Node a Color (Tree a) (Tree a)`

And also the signature of the insert:
`insert :: (Ord a) => a -> Tree a -> Tree a`

The question I'm worried about is that I want to insert all the values from the sheet into the structure, but I don't understand how to do this, because the new value must be called from the last state of the structure, can anyone help? I'm trying to do something like this:

```
add_elements:: Tree a -> [b] -> Tree a
add_elements t list= map ins $ list where
  ins x = insert x t    <-- data are always inserted in the same state of the structure
```

Comment: `map` maps lists to other lists. Not what you need here. Either use a fold or use explicit recursion on `list` (e.g. `add_elements t [] = .... ; add_elements t (x:xs) = ....`)

Answer (score 1):

You here create a list of `Tree`s where for each tree in the list, you have inserted an element from the `list` in the original tree, so if you use the empty tree and elements `2` and `5`, then you made a tree with `2` as element, and a tree with `5` as element.

You can work with [**`foldl :: Foldable f => (b -> a -> b) -> b -> f a -> b`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldl) to work wit an accumulator that starts with an initial element, and each time calls the function with that accumulator and the next item in a foldable (list) to obtain the next version of the accumulator.

This will thus look like:

```
addElements :: Ord a => Tree a -> [a] -> Tree a
addElements = foldl …
```

where I leave filling in the `…` part as an exercise.

Comment: I take it I have to implement my instance for foldl?

Comment: @student422: you don't need to implement `foldl` or a `Foldable` typeclass, that has already been done for lists. You only need to *use* `foldl`.

Comment: Why foldl instead of foldr or foldl'? I guess foldr will have trouble because insertion is strict, but foldl' should work, and I don't think foldl is any better than foldr, is it?

Comment: @amalloy: it depends in what order the elements should be inserted yes. But I guess indeed it should be `foldl'` or `foldr`.